# Databind value array to list datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a datatemplate for listbox:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Rectangle Width="10" Height="{Binding ???}" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

The ItemSource of the list is set to int[] array. What should I specify in Binding ??? to make the binding path take the concrete value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just **{Binding}**?

This will take the item itself.